# Spark initiator combined with low-voltage, high-current follow on

Tags: circuit-protection, spark

I am aiming to add a spark initiator to my electric discharge machining (EDM) circuit, but I am unsure of how combine the high voltage (>1-10 kV) initiator and the existing lower-voltage, higher-current (30 V, 4 A, 1 kHz) pulse train.

Both need to be connected across the spark gap, but I fear the high voltage of the spark initiator will damage the components of the 30 V circuit.

Usually I might use a diode for protection, but at these high voltages it seems tricky to find the right approach.

I also am weary of shunting approaches because those might kill the voltage spike at the gap, although it would protect my circuit.

What makes it harder is that I can't easily measure the duration of the actual spark initiator pulse (and therefore the power) with my scope due to the HV so I don't know if typical ESD components would work for example.

I feel like there may be a well known approach to this kind of problem I just don't know about.

Any thoughts appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

[There is a discussion here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/349156/ignition-coil-arc-initiation-with-protected-low-voltage-continuation) on a very similar topic that might be of use

> Ignition coil arc initiation with protected low voltage continuation?

Comment: Thanks, that was an interesting read. I also found a discussion https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/136036/do-serially-connected-diodes-share-equal-reverse-voltage to put diodes in series. However there are complexities requiring shunt capacitors and resistors.